# Covariance of two increasing stochastic processes

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

> Theorem
>
> For any two increasing functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with
>   finite $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]<\infty$,
>
> $$ \mathrm{cov}[f(X), g(X)]\geq 0 $$

The above basic theorem can be found in e.g., [1](http://www.math.tu-dresden.de/sto/schmidt/dsvm/dsvm2003-4.pdf). But it is used when $X$ is a random variable.

My question is what about $X(t)$ is a process? That is, if $f$ and $g$ are chosen such that $f(X(t))$ and $g(X(t))$ are almost surely increasing processes, will $ \mathrm{cov}[f(X(t)), g(X(t))]\geq 0 $ hold for any $t>0$?

Comment: are you fixing $t$?

Comment: yes, the covariance at any fixed $t$.

Comment: correct me if I am misunderstanding, but if you fix $t$ then $X(t)$ is a random variable, and in that case you can use the theorem above, or am I missing the point?

Comment: @RScrlli Note that here $f$ and $g$ are no longer increasing functions. So we can not use the theorem above. Those two functions let $f(X(t))$ and $g(X(t))$ be increasing *processes*. E.g., $f(X(t)) = \int^t_0 X^2(s) \,ds$ is an increasing process driven by $X(t)$.

Comment: ahh okey, I overlooked that!